# how to create a cclust object given a dataframe of indices

Tags: r, matlab, interface, cluster-analysis

I need to access a function clustIndex of cclust package in R.
The protoptype of the function is as follows:

```
clustIndex ( y, x, index = "all" )
y Object of class "cclust" returned by a clustering algorithm such as kmeans
x Data matrix where columns correspond to variables and rows to observations
index The indexes that are calculated "calinski", "cindex", "db", "hartigan",
      "ratkowsky", "scott", "marriot", "ball", "trcovw", "tracew", "friedman",
      "rubin", "ssi", "likelihood", and "all" for all the indexes. Abbreviations
      of these names are also accepted.
```

y is the object that is produced from function cclust in the same package, but I have a clustering algorithm coded in Matlab, and want to use this function clustIndex to calculate the indices using the solution produced by the algorithm in matlab.

One way I can think of is to create an object of cclust and fill value of its variable using my solutuion and then use it. Will this be correct/work?
Documentation of the package is available [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cclust/cclust.pdf)

Any other ideas to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create an object , you can just create a list like this:

```
  y = list(cluster = matlabObj$cluster , 
           centers = matlabObj$centers ,
           withins = matlabObj$withins,
           size = matlabObj$size)
```

Here an example using `cclust`(you should use your matlab cluster here) to show that the 4 variables are enough to use `clustIndex` function:

```
x<- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100,sd=0.3),ncol=2),
         matrix(rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=0.3),ncol=2))
matlabObj <- cclust(x,2,20,verbose=TRUE,method="kmeans")
clustIndex(matlabObj,x, index="all")

y = list(cluster = matlabObj$cluster , 
         centers = matlabObj$centers ,
         withins = matlabObj$withins,
         size = matlabObj$size)

identical(clustIndex(y,x, index="all"),
          clustIndex(matlabObj,x, index="all"))

[1] TRUE
```

Comment: As I am very less aware about the internal procedures for the indices, Are these four variables are sufficient to calculate indices?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja I edit my question to add an example. Hope it is clearer now.